# Modify a text file with some value by reading from another text file using shell script

Tags: shell

```
File1.txt
Name|City|Age
john|delhi|25
marry|london|45
phill|newyork|26

file2.txt
LA
Amsterdam
Mumbai
```

I need to replace the cities of file1.txt by cities of file2.txt. I am new  to shell script. Please help.

Comment: How do you want to replace, is there any sequence or condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ paste -d"|" <(cut -d"|" -f1 file1.txt) <(echo City; cat file2.txt) <(cut -d"|" -f3- file1.txt)
Name|City|Age
john|LA|25
marry|Amsterdam|45
phill|Mumbai|26
```